# Is it natural to ask, 'what do you think you are doing'?

Tags: questions, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

If someone's doing something bad or that will have a really bad influence on me, say, a brother just opens the windows wide on a windy  winter day while I'm having a fever, and I want him to explain himself. Instead of asking,

> What the hell are you doing?

Is it natural to ask,

> What do you think you are doing?

Comment: It's perfectly natural (or even "What the hell do you think you are doing?"). You can use it to someone misbehaving, whether or not it affects you personally.

Comment: [have a fever, unless you are using Indian English present progressive]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. [Bernadette said it to Sheldon and Amy](https://youtu.be/iWYgmPl7o64?t=140) in The Big Bang Theory s12.

> Bernadette: What do you think you're doing?
>
> Amy: I thought it was clear. I'm being unnecessarily hurtful but with
> a sweet voice.
>
> Sheldon: And I don't understand what's going on because I went to MIT.